# .htaccess append folder name to end of URLs

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We have a multi language site with product URLs in English like:

```
example.com/en/product-name
example.com/en/product-name2
```

Product names can have any latin character, number and dashes in them.

Due to a restructuring, all English URLs need to have `-en` appended to them like so:

```
example.com/en/product-name-en
example.com/en/product-name2-en
```

Can anyone help me to find `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` to match any URL with `/en/` in it and 301 redirect to the same URL with a `-en` appended at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like the following, using mod_rewrite, near the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEnging On

# Append "-en" to URL if it starts "/en/."
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-en$
RewriteRule ^en/[\w-]+$ %{REQUEST_URI}-en [R=301,L]
```

It is preferable to first test with a 302 (temporary) redirect in order to avoid caching issues.

`\w` is a shorthand character class that matches `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` and `_` (underscore), to which we add the `-` (hyphen) to the character class. (I assume you mean "hyphen", when you state "dashes" - although these are strictly different characters.)

The preceding condition (`RewriteCond` directive) is to avoid redirecting a URL that already ends with `-en`. The `!` prefix negates the regex.